# How to save multiple identical entities from one form in Spring Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a question, how to save multiple identical entities from one form in Spring Controller?
If I have the following code in html:

```
<form method="post" action="/dictionary/save">
<table>
... BEGIN jsp foreach function ...
<tr>
  <td><input type=hidden name="id" value="${entity.id}"></td>
  <td><input type=text name="en" value="${entity.en}"></td>
  <td><input type=text name="lv" value="${entity.lv}"></td>
  <td><input type=text name="ru" value="${entity.ru}"></td>
</tr>
... END jsp foreach function ...
</table>
<input type=submit value="Save">
</form>
```

In JSP listing can be till 50 entities. How to save its all in one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a modelAttribute of a domain object say .. dictionary which would have a list of some element (that you say can be 50 in the JSP)

in the JSP, use the modelAttribute in the form:form tag

and instead of input type use:

In Spring

```
class Dictionary{ 
   @Id     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   private String code;

   @Column
   private String ru;

   @Column
   private String lv;

   @Column
   private String en;
}
```

In Controller

```
List<Dictionary> diction=new ArrayList<Dictionary>();
model.addattribute("dictionary",diction);
```

In JSP

```
<form:form method="post" action="/dictionary/save" modelAttribute="dictionary">
<table><tr>
<td>
<form:input path="diction["+rowNum+"].code" />
<form:input path="diction["+rowNum+"].ru" />
<form:input path="diction["+rowNum+"].lv" />
<form:input path="diction["+rowNum+"].en" />
</td>

//code to add next td (either through javascript or jquery)
</form:form>
```

**Please see that 
1. tags wont work in javascript or jquery and you can have simple input tags as **

```
<input type="text" name="code"/>
```

This name input could be as many as you want

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a domain Entity Dictionary with the following code:

`@Entity
public class Dictionary {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code;
    @Column
    private String ru;
    @Column
    private String lv;
    @Column
    private String en;
...
}
`
And in controller I mind that I can add `@ModelAttribute("Dictionary")` so and over jsp in one form I can post into controller many Dictionary entities. Each line in JSP form is a different entity.

Comment: Modified the answer as per your comment.. :-)